# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called after reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller that needs to be updated through a delegate call. I have set the datasource and delegate and on initial load of the tableview, all works as expected. I have a delegate method that gets called after a datasource update. The delegate calls a refresh method in the table view controller class which calls .reloadData()

When reloadData is called, numberOfRowsInSection is called and accurately returns the number of rows, however cellForRowAtIndexPath never gets called.

In this particular case, numberOfRowsInSection returns 2, therefore cellForRowAtIndexPath should be called twice but it's called zero times.

On initial load everything is fine. It's only when reloadData is called taht cellForRowAtIndexPath is ignored. I have done this same thing many times in Obj-C without any weirdness. Are there any known issues with this in Swift?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(LayerMenuCell.reuseId) as! LayerMenuCell
    // ....
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(layerEntries?.count)
    return (layerEntries?.count)!
}

func refresh() {
    self.layersTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: See post for code. Code never enters cellForRow... when reloadData is called, even though numberOfRowsInSections returns an accurate number that is NOT zero

Comment: Check if you're using 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' and make sure its not returning ZERO.

Comment: have u directly call self.layersTableView.reloadData() ??

Comment: Set a break point at  return (layerEntries?.count)! and check that if your array is empty or not.
May be ARC dealloc array.

Comment: Even hard coding the value doesn't work, so I don't think this is the reason. Replacing the return statement with "return 2" has no effect

Comment: if reload table doesnt work, try calling relaodROws / reload sections and see if cellFor row is called or not. If number or rows is called, then cell for row shud get called too.

Comment: also check the answers in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042270/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-not-called-but-noof-rows-in-section-is-called

Comment: Do you perform the `reloadData` call on the main thread?

Comment: michi - thank you for reading my question thoroughly. In my question, I stated that the datasource/delegate were definitely set. This was a threading issue and calling reloadData on the main thread WAS the answer. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Pheepster: so you were calling `tableView.reloadData()` not on the main thread, I wonder why the `numberOfRowsInSection` was called anyway.

Comment: appzYourLife - that's a good question. I'm not sure why, but it works and I'm able to move on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `delegate` and `dataSource` of your `UITableView`:

```
myTable.delegate = self
myTable.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Both are set. As I mentioned in the post, the table view loads without issue during initial load. This would not occur if the datasource/delegate were not already set. In my case, numberOfRowsInSection is called, which would not be the case if the datasource/delegates weren't set

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the Documentation:

> A functioning table view requires three table view data source
>   methods.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

MAake sure you implement the above three delegate methods and they return some values other than nil or 0.

There is a chance that cell height could be 0/ table height is 0 in both the cases cell for row method will not get called.

Also make sure you set the delegate properly and call the reloadData method on main thread. More on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827127/uitableviewcontroller-will-not-call-cellforrowatindexpath-but-numberofsectionsin)

Comment: As mentioned in my other comments, all of these functions return accurately. Even hard coding the values has no effect. Furthermore, if these methods were improperly implemented, the table view would not work on initial load, but it DOES work on initial load. It only fails when reloadData is called.

Answer (score -2):

Things you need to check when Tableview is not working as expected:
1. Setting the delegate and datasource through storyboard or by code.

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

2.check if tableView in storyboard is connected to tableView outlet.
3.check numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInT‌​ableView returning the correct values.
4.check if the methods is written properly.
5.add the delegate and datasource after UIViewController.

```
<UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>
```

this will help you if you are missing any thing.

Comment: Again, if delegate were not properly set, numberOfRowsInSection would not be called, but it is. The only tableview delegate method that is NOT called is cellForRowAtIndexPath.